# Is there a way to remove one file from a full git history and releases/tags?

Tags: git, github, bfg-repo-cleaner

I commited my imprint to a now big project and pushed it to github.
The problem: At that time i lived with my parents.
Because i don't wanted to leak my parents Adress, i made the Repo private.
Now i want to make the repo public, because it should be completely open-source.

So far i tried deleting the file from the whole git history, but failed every time.
Once i got so far, that i got the file deleted, but it was still in the tags and Releases.
I've "studied" through many Posts and Articles but failed every time.

Is there any way to remove the file from the whole git history AND the releases/tags?
P.S: If anyone wants to answer with some code snippets, the file is stored under: "/homepage/rechtliches.html"

Comment: GitHub keep every commit forever *unless* you get the GitHub folks to clean old ones out. In all cases, when rewriting history, you get new commits that you must use in place of the old ones.

Comment: Also see [github’s own docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#fully-removing-the-data-from-github) on what to do (tldr fix the repo history, and then contact them).